# Best way to build lib that supports class 'new' webpack.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I try to figure out how to build lib from scratch, and minify with webpack.
So my lib work perfect, and I want to minify it with webpack. When I minify webpack remove all my class.

myLib1.js

```
export default class MyClass1 {
    constructor(value1) {
        this.value1= value1;
    }

    selectable(options) {
        console.log('this is value from myClass1', value1);
    }
}
```

myLib2.js

```
export default class MyClass2 {
    constructor(value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    selectable(options) {
        console.log('this is value from myClass2', value2);
    }
}
```

index.js I try two things

```
import MyClass1 from "./myLib1";
import MyClass2 from "./myLib2";
export { MyClass1, MyClass1 };
```

and

```
export * from "./myLib1";
export * from "./myLib2";
```

webpack.config.js -> this is what build index.min.js my final lib for production.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: [
        
            './src/js/index.js',
            './src/js/mylib1.js',
            './src/js/mylib2.js'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: './',
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css'
        })
    ]
}
```

Then when I want to use it like this:

```
import { MyClass1, MyClass2 } from './index.min.js';

const myClass1 = new MyClass1(one);
const myClass2 = new MyClass1(two);
const myClass3 = new MyClass2(three);
const myClass4 = new MyClass2(four);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your library runs in node you need to specify the target on webpack in order to expose a module in other case webpack is gonna try your bundle as he need to run in a browser (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) and try to encapsulate everything also need to specify the library target as `umd`

By the other hand you should define one entry and from there export what you want in your library, so in the entry object you just need to put the path for your `index.js` file.

webpack config change it to

```js
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: {
        index: './src/js/index.js',
    },
    output:{
      // output stuff
      libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
 // everything else
```

index file should be like your first try:

```js
import MyClass1 from "./myLib1";
import MyClass2 from "./myLib2";
export { MyClass1, MyClass1 };
```

good luck

Comment: I add my lib to github https://github.com/deicidemilan/imp_ui. I think it's better to take a on real example. I just need now to build minify this code and use it in other backend project. I try to add libraryTarget: 'umd' and library: '$' but no luck.

Comment: Can't see that repo, I get a 404...  maybe you can invite me if is private my user name is "castiarena"

Comment: Hey I actually found perfect solution on this article. https://dev.to/riversun/recipes-on-how-to-create-a-library-that-supports-both-browser-and-node-js-201m#(1). Thanks anyway.